# read content from Twitter sample using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm pretty new to programming, and recently have been playing with Twitter API. From statuses/sample method, how would you read the content of following URL using Javascript?

https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json

Edit: perhaps I shall explain my intention. I'm trying to read the Twitter sample data, read the hashtags every 30 seconds, and then sort them ascendingly every 30 seconds the top 10 hashtags.

The problem is, I'm not even sure how to read the Twitter data in the first place..

Not looking for solutions, but definitely could use some ideas.. especially for getting started.

Comment: Be careful pointing anything at the twitter firehose!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to utilize JSONP which is a special type of response back from the server.

It basically takes the response, wraps it in an anonymous function callback, and returns it to the client inside of a script tag thereby calling it when the response gets back to the browser.

```
​$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/msdn.json?count=10&callback=?',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }    
});​
```

Inspecting the request url in Chrome's debugger you'll see the request...

https://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/msdn.json?count=10&callback=jQuery1706531336647458375_1335842234009&_=1335842234045

And the response back is...

```
jQuery1706531336647458375_1335842234009( /* data */ );
```

Then jQuery wraps the data in the script tag and appends it to the body.

Notice how the callback in the request matches the function call in the response.

Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry... I'm having trouble understanding your code.. I must have stressed that I'm a complete noob.. how exactly do I get this to work?

Comment: The url you have in your sample doesn't work because it is on https, but the `$.ajax()` code from the example above should be all that you need. Just replace the URL with the one you are wanting to hit. The `data` in `function (data) {` is the response from the URL.

Comment: in Unix terminal you can use:

[curl https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json? -uAnyTwitterUser:Password']

to display the sample stream... I guess I'm looking for a similar way to do it in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Read up on cross site scripting.

Basically you're going to need to proxy your request through the hosting server.

Comment: You most certainly *can* load json cross-site. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and http://jsfiddle.net/4sBfK/

Comment: Technically you're both slightly off, @arychj is correct in saying that you cannot request JSON cross site, however you CAN do it using JSONP which is actually what philwinkle you have going on with your fiddle there and the `jsoncallback=?`. Take a look at my answer above and it should show you a little about JSONP...